# dropdown submenu of last child to left

Tags: html, css

```
#headermenu ul ul ul {
    position: absolute; 
    left: 100%; 
    top:0;
}
```

i have the above css to make the submenu of all my dropdown to go right. my question is how to make the last submenu of the dropdown to go right(the last-child).tried several approach as

```
#headermenu ul ul ul:last-child  { 
position: absolute; 
right: 100%; 
top:0; 
}
```

but it not doing the thing i want it to do.also tried it this way

```
#headermenu ul ul ul:last-child { 
direction: rtl; }
```

again its not working any idea are appreciated

Comment: share your markup and `rtl` is for right to left, not for positioning elements

Comment: Give the Fiddle as an example for people to mess around with.

Comment: give right:0; instead of right:100%

Comment: @Ruddy here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guradio/gvmRX/...you can make something out of it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#headermenu ul ul ul:last-child  { 
    position: absolute; 
    left: -100%; 
    top:0;  
}
```

it worked please criticeze if it is a good practice or not

Answer (score 1):

right should be `0` not `100%`

```
#headermenu ul ul ul:last-child  { 
position: absolute; 
right: 0; 
top:0; 
}
```

Comment: if i put left 0 it will be where the dropdown is i tried -100% it worked my question is it a good practice?

Answer (score 0):

Add this css

```
#headermenu ul ul ul:last-of-type
{ 
position: absolute; 
right: 0; 
top:0; 
}
```